# How to order by - Flutter Firestore data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have this method that retrieves data from the `firestore` service. I want to `order` the data by the `timeDate` value which holds the date in the format `yyyy-MM-dd` **but in string** type date type.

This is where I retrieve and it doesn't work somehow. (no error, but doesn't group by)

```
  // get the news
  Stream<List<News>> getNews() {
    return _db.collection("news").orderBy("timeNews", descending: true).snapshots().map(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.documents
              .map((doc) => News.fromMap(doc.data, doc.documentID))
              .toList(),
        ) ;
  }
```

This is the `News` model

```
class News {
  final String headline;
  final String description;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String timeNews;
  final String timeDate;
  final String priority;
  String id;


  News({this.headline,this.description, this.imageUrl, this.timeNews, this.timeDate, this.priority, this.id});

  News.fromMap(Map<String,dynamic> data, String id):
    headline=data['headline'], 
    description=data['description'], 
    imageUrl=data['imageUrl'],
    timeNews=data['timeNews'],
    timeDate=data['timeDate'],
    priority=data['priority'],
    id=id;

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap(){
    return {
      "headline" : headline,
      "description": description,
      "imageUrl": imageUrl,
      "timeNews": timeNews,
      "timeDate": timeDate,
      "priority": priority,
      "id": id,
    };
  }
}
```

Can someone help me?

I even trie but no luck so far

```
  // get the news
  Stream<List<News>> getNews() {
    return _db.collection("news").orderBy(DateTime.parse("timeDate"), descending: true).snapshots().map(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.documents
              .map((doc) => News.fromMap(doc.data, doc.documentID))
              .toList(),
        ) ;
  }
```

Comment: It is a good practice to store time in Timestamp. You can always convert Timestamp to DateTime and then DateTime to String on client side.